# Split string Swift without introducing Newlines

Tags: swift, string

In Swift, when you want to separate a string in multiple lines, because is too long, you can do this:

```
let string = """
             A
             B
             C
             D
             E
             """
```

But this method introduces Newline between each line:

```
print(string)

// Prints: A\nB\nC\nD\nE
```

Is it possible to separate a very long string in multiple lines (for code visibility reasons), avoiding Newlines?

Comment: Please read [String Literals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID286) in the Language Guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

End a line with a backslash to suppress the subsequent newline. Like this:

```
let string = """
             A \
             B \
             C \
             D \
             E
             """
```